# Definitive country list for e-commerce applications

Tags: sql, e-commerce, web-applications

I am looking for a list of countries for use in the development of an e-commerce app including:

Country Name,
Country Code,
Language,
etc.

While only the country name (and probably the country code) are really necessary, some of the other info may be nice (as long as there isn't too much!).  I used to have a good list but I can't find it anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check **ISO 3166-1** for country codes.

There are 3 sets of country codes:

- ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2
- ISO 3166-1 Alpha-3
- ISO 3166-1 Numeric

For the list of all 3 sets, view here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Answer (score 5):

ISO (International Standards Organization) maintains a list of countries [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements).

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia, as usual, has a pretty definitive list. It's not in a readily computer-readable form, but it shouldn't take long to massage it, if you can't find anything else:

[ISO_3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) (country codes)

[List of sovereign states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states) (countries and their languages)

Answer (score 0):

Several options for "[country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code)" but ISO is probably best

Language will be difficult because it's often many per country. Take Switzerland where I am: do you support French/German only? Include Italian (many sites don't). And for the handful of Romansch...?

Answer (score 0):

http://cldr.unicode.org/ - common standard multilanguage database include country list  and other localizable data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the curated and regularly updated country list data available in CSV and JSON formats (ISO 3166-1):

https://datahub.io/core/country-list

If you need more comprehensive country codes, e.g., ISO3166-1-Alpha-2, ISO3166-1-Alpha-3, ITU dialing codes, ISO 4217 currency codes, and many others:

https://datahub.io/core/country-codes

There is a data set for language codes as well. ISO Language Codes (639-1 and 693-2) and IETF Language Types:

https://datahub.io/core/language-codes

For more reference data you can take a look at:

https://datahub.io/awesome/reference-data

Good luck!